# Got an Error !! While Uploading a file in Node js using Formidable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, mern

I'm trying to understand and resolve this error message I'm getting while renaming a file with `fs`, uploaded using Formidable in Node.js.

### Code

```js
const formidable = require('formidable');
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
http.createServer((req,res) => {
    if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
        const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){

            var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;
            var newpath = '/`home`/invincibleanurag/Desktop/Nodes/upload/'+ files.filetoupload.originalFilename;
            
            fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
                res.end();
            });
        })
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'})
        res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
        res.write('<input type="submit">');
        res.write('</form>');
        return res.end("Over")
    }
}).listen(8080)
```

### Error Message

```
node:internal/fs/utils:699
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "oldPath" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
    at Object.rename (node:fs:1011:13)
    at /home/invincibleanurag/Desktop/Nodes/node.js:10:16
    at zalgoSafe (/home/invincibleanurag/Desktop/Nodes/node_modules/dezalgo/dezalgo.js:20:10)
    at f (/home/invincibleanurag/Desktop/Nodes/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (/home/invincibleanurag/Desktop/Nodes/node_modules/formidable/dist/index.cjs:1210:7)
    at IncomingForm.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (/home/invincibleanurag/Desktop/Nodes/node_modules/formidable/dist/index.cjs:1661:10)
    at /home/invincibleanurag/Desktop/Nodes/node_modules/formidable/dist/index.cjs:1420:14 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Often, error messages are very simple to follow. This one is telling you that your variable `oldpath` is not a `string` like you're expecting it to be. Without more details such as the file itself, it's hard to pinpoint exactly WHY this is the case.

However, you should (as all beginners do) place a `console.log(files.filetoupload.filepath);` right below `var oldpath = ...`. Does it look like a string in console? If not, maybe log the `files.filetoupload`.